# vec_sel in SHA-1

Tags: sha-256, sha-1

I can't find what is `vec_sel()` in this optimization from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1_pseudocode):

> Instead of the formulation from the original FIPS PUB 180-1 shown, the following equivalent expressions may be used to compute f in the main loop above:
>
> ```
> Bitwise choice between c and d, controlled by b.
> (0  ≤ i ≤ 19): f = d xor (b and (c xor d))                (alternative 1)
> (0  ≤ i ≤ 19): f = (b and c) xor ((not b) and d)          (alternative 2)
> (0  ≤ i ≤ 19): f = (b and c) xor ((not b) and d)          (alternative 3)
> (0  ≤ i ≤ 19): f = vec_sel(d, c, b)                       (alternative 4)
>  
> Bitwise majority function.
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = (b and c) or (d and (b or c))          (alternative 1)
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = (b and c) or (d and (b xor c))         (alternative 2)
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = (b and c) xor (d and (b xor c))        (alternative 3)
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = (b and c) xor (d and (b xor c))        (alternative 4)
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = (b and c) xor (b and d) xor (c and d)  (alternative 5)
> (40 ≤ i ≤ 59): f = vec_sel(c, b, c xor d)                 (alternative 6)
> ```

Comment: Based on the text and the equivalent descriptions, it seems like a vectorized multiplexer where every bit of $b$ decides whether to pick the corresponding bit from $d$ or $c$.

Comment: @SEJPM Looks like [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/compiler_ref/vec_sel.html): *"For d=vec_sel(a, b, c): Each bit of the result vector has the value of the corresponding bit of a if the corresponding bit of c is 0, or the value of the corresponding bit of b otherwise."*

Comment: Okay so it's like the $ch()$ function then, which "choose" either bit $b$ or bit $c$ based on the value of bit $a$ (or whatever order of $a$, $b$, $c$ may be used)